# How to set default layout parameters for button styles?

Tags: android, android-layout

I constantly have to manually the layout parameters to my buttons

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/signIn"
    android:layout_above="@+id/forgotPassword"
    android:text="@string/button_sign_in" 

<!-- Repetitive part -->
    android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/button_margin_left"
    android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/button_margin_right"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
```

My styles.xml

```
<style name="myButton" parent="android:style/Widget.Button">
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/button_textColor</item>
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/button_background</item>      
    <item name="android:textSize">@dimen/button_textSize</item>
    <item name="android:padding">@dimen/button_padding</item>
    <item name="android:layout_width">fill_parent</item>
    <item name="android:layout_marginLeft">@dimen/button_margin_left</item>
    <item name="android:layout_marginRight">@dimen/button_margin_right</item>
</style>
```

However the last three values seem to have no affect!
If I can't set it in the styles xml, can I set up eclipse to change the default values it creates when using the graphical layout?

Comment: have you set `style="myButton"`?

Comment: @Bicou yerp, the other values: textSize, textColor, background and padding are all inherited

Answer (score 3):

I didn't have room in the comments section, so here's my (working) code, for a `TextView`

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/show_sa_j"
    style="@style/show_title"
    android:text="@string/loading" />
```

---

```
<style name="show_title">
    <item name="android:textSize">34dp</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">#FFFFFFFF</item>
    <item name="android:gravity">center_horizontal</item>
    <item name="android:paddingLeft">10dp</item>
    <item name="android:paddingRight">10dp</item>
    <item name="android:layout_width">fill_parent</item>
    <item name="android:layout_height">wrap_content</item>
</style>
```

The result is:

[image: result in the Eclipse Layout Editor]

As you can see, the `TextView` is filling its parent in width (minus the parent's padding).

Just to prove that layout margin works aswell, I added `<item name="android:layout_marginLeft">25dp</item>` to my styles and here's the result:

[image]